# Trouble Building `github/mdn/content` with `yarn build`: `env-cmd`, `cross-env`, and `yari-build` Missing

Tags: node.js, build, path, hadoop-yarn

I'm encountering an issue while trying to compile the `mdn/content` repository from GitHub using `yarn build` on Windows. In my `package.json`, the `build` script seems to be attempting to execute `env-cmd`, `cross-env`, and `yari-build` without leveraging `npx`.

Here's what I've tried:

1. I added `npx` before the three commands (`env-cmd`, `cross-env`, and `yari-build`). As a result, `npx` successfully found `env-cmd` and `cross-env`, but it couldn't locate `yari-build`.
2. I attempted to install `yari-build` using `npm install yari-build`, but it didn't find the package.

I attempted to run the yarn build command on Windows, expecting that it would automatically find the relevant npm packages based on the system’s `PATH`. However, in reality, it required manual guidance through `npx`, and even after doing so, it still couldn’t locate the necessary content.

Now I'm wondering:

- Should I modify my `PATH` environment variable to address this issue?
- Is it recommended to globally install the missing packages (`env-cmd`, `cross-env`, and `yari-build`)?
- Are there any other steps I should take to resolve this?